# UPnP from commandline in linux

Tags: linux, upnp

Is there a utility to forward ports on a simple home networking wireless router from commandline using upnp?

Answer (score 16):

Check out [MiniUPNP Project](http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/).

Comment: To install on Ubuntu: `sudo apt install miniupnpc`

To add a port forward: `upnpc -a 192.168.1.2 22 3333 TCP`

To remove a port forward: `upnpc -d 3333 TCP`

Info from https://po-ru.com/2013/02/17/using-upnp-igd-for-simpler-port-forwarding

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [miniupnpc library test client](http://miniupnp.free.fr).
Use `$ upnpc -r PORT PROTOCOL` to automatically forward *port* to your current machine.

Example:

`$ upnpc -r 13 TCP`

…forwards port 13 to local port 13 when TCP is used.

On correct execution it will print a message like:

`external 203.0.113.0:13 TCP is redirected to internal 192.168.1.5:13 (duration=604800)`

…where `192.168.1.5` is your LAN IP and `203.0.113.0` you WAN (public Internet) IP.